# React Native finishes in timeout on splash screen while detox test

Tags: react-native, detox

**Description**

I have problem with timeout and I don't know why. It asks for permissions and then it set the permissions (probably). In this moment app looks loaded, but after that there will show black screen with spinner for a moment and then splash screen. In this moment the app is stuck.

I found few issues about timeout, but I tried a lot wrote there but nothing worked. My colleague tried to run Detox on the same project with the same package versions and it was without problem.Hhe had the same versions of React Native, XCode, Node, Mocha and Detox.

**What I tried:**

- Few versions of Node: 8.1.3, 8.9.1 and 9.1.0
- Reinstall Node
- Delete and install node_modules again (yarn/npm)
- Change Detox versions: 5.9.4 and 5.8.1
- Change Mocha versions: 4.0.1 and 3.5.2
- Delete and install App in ios simulator
- upgrade XCode (9.0.1 –> 9.1)
- Recreate detox builds,
- Delete npm cache
- Delete detox cache

**Test:**

```
describe('Permissions', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.launchApp({permissions: {
      notifications: 'YES',
      location: 'always',
    }});
    await device.reloadReactNative()
  });

  it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
    await element(by.id('searchCarsButton')).tap()
  })
})
```

**Detox, Node, Device, Xcode and macOS Versions**

- Detox: 5.9.4, 5.8.1
- Node: 8.1.3
- Device: ios simulator
- Xcode: 9.1
- macOS: Sierra
- React Native: 0.44.0

**Device and verbose Detox logs**

```
$ detox test --loglevel verbose
node_modules/.bin/mocha e2e --opts e2e/mocha.opts  --loglevel verbose    

detox-server info 14:33:10: server listening on localhost:50396...
detox verb ws onOpen [object Object]
detox verb ws send: {"type":"login","params":{"sessionId":"c14ee5fe-de13-5f60-b61f-ff487043587b","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"loginSuccess","params":{"sessionId":"c14ee5fe-de13-5f60-b61f-ff487043587b","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox verb ws  
detox verb 1: applesimutils --list "iPhone 7" --maxResults=1 
detox info 1: Searching for device matching iPhone 7... 
detox verb 1: stdout: [
detox verb 1: stdout:   {
detox verb 1: stdout:     "state" : "Booted",
detox verb 1: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 1: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 7",
detox verb 1: stdout:     "udid" : "2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29",
detox verb 1: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 1: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 1: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 1: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 1: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 1: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 1: stdout:     }
detox verb 1: stdout:   }
detox verb 1: stdout: ]
detox verb 1: stdout: 
detox verb 2: applesimutils --list 
detox verb 2: stdout: [
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple TV",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "2F518141-A525-47B9-9A33-E5AEE34A92FA",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "tvOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15J580"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple TV 4K",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "EA308CF4-5A1F-41EC-AB1C-9E081C6860B4",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "tvOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15J580"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple TV 4K (at 1080p)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "4A9D24CE-469A-4BA9-86C5-6A6418B906B1",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "tvOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15J580"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPad (5th generation)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "BDD2070B-24B7-4748-9FCD-1A7A542B1741",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPad Air",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "EE452C63-A1CB-47A4-9DDE-3C85586C4AB0",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPad Air 2",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "8D7EE2CD-A09B-41A9-B7B5-0FEC4634AE1C",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "3487A5FF-3C7C-495A-BC8C-2B805908F3AB",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "EF72BAC9-BD3B-422A-917B-259E1D4F049D",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "76F7BFE5-981E-4799-A42D-2B2C75CF6B89",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "81042BB1-C6D3-4C50-98B6-5DDD226C0A24",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 5s",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "DC5CBF57-1804-4FB1-84B1-B47D32371F8D",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 6",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "0073B75C-D6DF-4F35-981E-965420C1F660",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 6 Plus",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "A8FC2524-4819-49F2-8694-FB03C27C68EE",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 6s",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "4B963220-4BD9-4389-AB2D-D5B739578F86",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 6s Plus",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "4973CA12-2A69-42ED-A2C2-42AAB9FB2DB7",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Booted",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 7",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "9D7D03DD-10CE-4529-A356-62479A5A6C6A",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 8",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "4C3124D0-5353-4471-BB7B-9D9FB30298A7",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone 8 Plus",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "D5350B7C-B7F9-4F36-B2F4-6D97D63C4869",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone SE",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "6EA12F63-932D-456B-B74F-68732DC65EFE",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "iPhone X",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "30AB0A5F-1E84-4747-AC74-882A0823177F",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "iOS 11.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15B87"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple Watch - 38mm",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "E0A4995F-4B50-4E6A-B13C-FC8863F4A677",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "watchOS 4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-4-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15R844"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple Watch - 42mm",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "4CD40B3E-A994-4852-9058-22EAC2B26882",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "watchOS 4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-4-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15R844"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "F9A49912-44A6-40EF-AC72-224E05461CF2",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "watchOS 4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-4-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15R844"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "F23C9051-AF9B-401E-8DEC-B19BA31C7C0E",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "watchOS 4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-4-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15R844"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "16D30FC1-9D10-462B-B28C-1DC54D6D78D0",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "watchOS 4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-4-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15R844"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   },
detox verb 2: stdout:   {
detox verb 2: stdout:     "state" : "Shutdown",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "udid" : "FE83E863-043D-4BB8-8C6F-3E0D5C39DD18",
detox verb 2: stdout:     "os" : {
detox verb 2: stdout:       "version" : "4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "availability" : "(available)",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "name" : "watchOS 4.1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-4-1",
detox verb 2: stdout:       "buildversion" : "15R844"
detox verb 2: stdout:     }
detox verb 2: stdout:   }
detox verb 2: stdout: ]
detox verb 2: stdout: 
detox verb 3: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall 2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29 com.creativedock.hoppycar 
detox info 3: Uninstalling com.creativedock.hoppycar... 
detox info 3: com.creativedock.hoppycar uninstalled 
detox verb 4: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/droover/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hoppycar.app 
detox info 4: Installing /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/droover/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hoppycar.app... 
detox info 4: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/droover/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hoppycar.app installed 
detox verb 5: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate 2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29 com.creativedock.hoppycar 
detox info 5: Terminating com.creativedock.hoppycar... 
detox info 5: com.creativedock.hoppycar terminated 
detox verb 6: /bin/cat /dev/null >$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/janvaclavik/Library/Detox/ios/dcbded2050005ff99b0bffc826182a2fb35fa7a4/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err 2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29 com.creativedock.hoppycar --args -detoxServer ws://localhost:50396 -detoxSessionId c14ee5fe-de13-5f60-b61f-ff487043587b 
detox info 6: Launching com.creativedock.hoppycar... 
detox verb 6: stdout: com.creativedock.hoppycar: 28279
detox verb 6: stdout: 
detox info 6: com.creativedock.hoppycar launched. The stdout and stderr logs were recreated, you can watch them with:
        tail -F $HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.{out,err} 
detox verb ws send: {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"ready","messageId":-1000,"params":{}}
detox verb ws  
  Permissions
detox verb 7: applesimutils --simulator 2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29 --bundle com.creativedock.hoppycar --setPermissions notifications=YES,location=always 
detox info 7: Trying to set permissions... 
detox info 7: Permissions are set 
detox verb 8: /bin/cat /dev/null >$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/janvaclavik/Library/Detox/ios/dcbded2050005ff99b0bffc826182a2fb35fa7a4/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err 2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29 com.creativedock.hoppycar --args -detoxServer ws://localhost:50396 -detoxSessionId c14ee5fe-de13-5f60-b61f-ff487043587b 
detox info 8: Launching com.creativedock.hoppycar... 
detox verb 8: stdout: com.creativedock.hoppycar: 28306
detox verb 8: stdout: 
detox info 8: com.creativedock.hoppycar launched. The stdout and stderr logs were recreated, you can watch them with:
        tail -F $HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2EE82BFA-2351-4627-937C-B93904827F29/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.{out,err} 
detox verb ws send: {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"ready","messageId":-1000,"params":{}}
detox verb ws  
detox verb ws send: {"type":"reactNativeReload","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"ready","messageId":-1000,"params":{}}
detox verb ws  
detox verb ws send: {"type":"invoke","params":{"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForAccessibilityID:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"searchCarsButton"}]}}]}},"method":"performAction:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYActions"},"method":"actionForTap","args":[]}}]},"messageId":1}
    1) should have welcome screen

detox verb ws send: {"type":"cleanup","params":{"stopRunner":true},"messageId":2}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"cleanupDone","messageId":2,"params":{}}
detox verb ws  

  0 passing (3m)
  1 failing

  1) Permissions should have welcome screen:
     Error: Timeout of 135000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.


child_process.js:631
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/mocha e2e --opts e2e/mocha.opts  --loglevel verbose    
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:588:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:628:13)
    at runMocha (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:56:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:36:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
```

**detox.last_launch_app_log.{out,err}:**

```
...
2017-11-13 12:20:55.393 dr[26453:980543] ☣️ DETOX:: Ignoring timer: 35 failure reason: "duration>1.5"
2017-11-13 12:20:57.402 dr[26453:980543] ☣️ DETOX:: Ignoring timer: 36 failure reason: "duration>1.5"
2017-11-13 12:20:59.410 dr[26453:980543] ☣️ DETOX:: Ignoring timer: 37 failure reason: "duration>1.5"
...
```

Comment: We are having the same issue and still no resolution. Same RN version. Unfortunately, it is not that easy to upgrade RN, so we might not use detox which is really sad.

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually giving you the problem. "For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;"

I believe your issue is that you are turning the functions into promises with the async and the test framework does not know when thet are done.

Remove your async/await and just use a normal .then() and when finished, call the done() function. That should end the test.

More info here: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code